# Unable to pass data from variable in XAML - Xamarin Forms, map app

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm completely stuck at this.

Below is a working code, everything is fine and I can see expected map but...

```xml
<maps:Map Grid.Row="7" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
    <x:Arguments>
        <maps:MapSpan>
            <x:Arguments>
                <maps:Position>
                    <x:Arguments>
                        <x:Double>39.808056</x:Double>
                        <x:Double>-5.696944</x:Double>
                    </x:Arguments>
                </maps:Position>
                <x:Double>0.01</x:Double>
                <x:Double>0.01</x:Double>
            </x:Arguments>
        </maps:MapSpan>
    </x:Arguments>
</maps:Map>
```

When I try to use a variable, everything falls apart.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.Maps;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Maps"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="ProjectNuke.Views.ItemDetailPage"
             Title="{Binding Title}">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <Label Text="{Binding Item.Latitude}" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="Small"/>
        <Label Text="Longtitude:" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="0"/>
        <Label Text="{Binding Item.Longtitude}" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="Small"/>
        <maps:Map Grid.Row="7" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <x:Arguments>
                <maps:MapSpan>
                    <x:Arguments>
                        <maps:Position>
                            <x:Arguments>
                                <x:Double>{Binding Item.Latitude}</x:Double>
                                <x:Double>{Binding Item.Longtitude}</x:Double>
                            </x:Arguments>
                        </maps:Position>
                        <x:Double>0.01</x:Double>
                        <x:Double>0.01</x:Double>
                    </x:Arguments>
                </maps:MapSpan>
            </x:Arguments>
        </maps:Map>

    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

It seems like `{Binding Item.Latitude}` doesn't provide a Value, and the map shows an ocean :(

Please help!

Comment: what is your BindingContext?  Does it have a public property named "Item"?

Comment: Yes it has. BindingContext = this.viewModel = viewModel;

    {
        public Item Item { get; set; }
        public ItemDetailViewModel(Item item = null)
        {
            Title = item?.Text;
            Item = item;
        }
    }

Comment: I'm not positive that binding can be used this way - you might have to set the values in the code behind

Comment: Awesome advice! Redone code in a viewmodel and its working! Thanks man!

Comment: You could post the solution and accept it .Which will help more people .

Answer (score 0):

The `x:Arguments` you are providing the Map control, are constructor arguments for the control. Hence you will not be able to bind these values.

You will need to change your code to use the `MoveToRegion` method on the Map control instead.

If you are using the MVVM design pattern, you would probably listen to changes to your Region or Latitude and Longitude properties and adjust the region accordingly.

So in your ViewModel:

```cs
private MapSpan _region;
public MapSpan Region
{
    get => _region;
    set
    {
        _region = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Region));
    }
}
```

And in your View:

```cs
ViewModel.NotifyPropertyChanged += OnNotifyPropertyChanged;

private void OnNotifyPropertyChanged(object sender, NotifyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
{
     if (args.PropertyName == nameof(MapSpan))
     {
         Map.MoveToRegion(ViewModel.Region);
     }
}
```